# Creating a List from a Data Frame in Python, is Adding the Index as Well

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

From a list of names I created (greater_three), I want to find all the names in that list in my DataFrame (new), and amend those values "location coordinates" in that DataFrame to a new list. But when I append I am also taking an index value.

```
    location = []
    for name in new['DBA Name']:
        if name in greater_three:
           location.append(new['Location'])
        else:
            pass
    Location
```

My output list (location) should like like this:

```
[[41.7770923949, -87.6060037796],
[41.7770923949, -87.6060037796],
[41.7770923949, -87.6060037796],
```

But I am getting it with an Index like this:

```
[0     (41.777092394888655, -87.60600377956905)
 1       (41.78457591499572, -87.6547753761994)
 2       (41.74427989606148, -87.5716351762223)
 3       (41.69164609748754, -87.6422140544927)
```

Also, smaller issue but I'm curious, it is iterating many times through (after I removed all the duplicate names from the data frame) like below, it should only have length of 26 coordinates (25 including 0):

```
 22    (41.901086765978654, -87.74854019856667)
 23     (41.70774046981763, -87.64300283870763)
 24     (41.75937734623751, -87.66111539963164)
 25     (41.75655095611123, -87.61068980246957)
 Name: Location, dtype: object,
 0     (41.777092394888655, -87.60600377956905)
 1       (41.78457591499572, -87.6547753761994)
 2       (41.74427989606148, -87.5716351762223)
...
23     (41.70774046981763, -87.64300283870763)
24     (41.75937734623751, -87.66111539963164)
25     (41.75655095611123, -87.61068980246957)
 Name: Location, dtype: object,
 0     (41.777092394888655, -87.60600377956905)
 1       (41.78457591499572, -87.6547753761994)
 2       (41.74427989606148, -87.5716351762223)
 3       (41.69164609748754, -87.6422140544927)
```

My columns look like this, I just need the coordinates in a list, I can take from either: 'Longitutude'and 'Latitude' or 'Location'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkA83.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every name, you're just re-appending the whole column to your list, rather than just the entries correspond to each name in your loop. You can fix this using `.loc` and filtering on where the names match. You should also `.drop_duplicates` in your `new['DBA Name']` to go through to avoid appending the same thing several times. Also your `else: pass` is not required. Your location column is tuples, but you want the output to be a list, so you'll need to covert that. See below:

```
 location = []
 for name in new['DBA Name'].drop_duplicates():
        if name in greater_three:
           location.append(list(new.loc[new['DBA Name'] == name, 'Location'].iloc[0]))

 location
```

Comment: Ok that gives me this '[['(41.777092394888655, -87.60600377956905)']` so the best solution I can see would be taking from the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' Column each (image above) but when I try to combine `...['DBA Name'] == name, 'Latitude', 'Longitude...' I get error Too Many Indexers, and if I use '['DBA Name'] == name, 'Latitude' and 'Longitude']...` I only get the second column 'Longitude'. Is there a way to get both at the same time? Or do I need two lists and use something like 'insert' to combine? Thanks.

Comment: @Gazoo to index on both columns, they need to be a list (and both exist in the dataframe, otherwise you get errors). So: `new.loc[new['DBA Name'] == name, ['Latitude', 'Longitude']]`

Comment: Ok I tried this `location.append(new.loc([new['DBA Name'] == name, ['Latitude', 'Longitude']].to_list())) ` and got `'list' object has no attribute 'to_list'`. I have created two lists from both columns seperately and combined them, because I couldn't figure this part out.

Comment: @Gazoo it's really hard for me to be able to tell you any more without knowing what your new dataframe looks like. Maybe you could add a few lines of it into the question as an example? As text/code, not a screenshot please

Comment: @Gazoo I have updated my answer using your screen shot. In future, you should add all data/code in your actual answer, not just as a screenshot. Hopefully the changes help, if so please accept this answer

Comment: your previous answer was more correct, but I needed it all in a list like I showed above, yours put it in a string '[['(41.777092394888655, -87.60600377956905)']` , but I realized that there may not be a simple way since values appear in `tuple` so I went back and took from your previous solution and created two lists from the other columns 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' and then combined them. That worked, no extra paranthesis or strings, but involved a lot more steps. Thanks